# UISegmentControl not executing target method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a tableViewCell subclass in which there is a segmentControl.I am trying to add target to it which is not working .What is the issue?

I have added it in a XIB file and declared it like this.

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *deckSwitch;
@end
```

And in `viewDidLoad` I am setting target like this.

```
[myCell.deckSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(selectDeckView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];  //Also tried UIContolEventTouchUpInside,but doesn't work.
```

and using it like this.

```
-(void)selectDeckView:(UISegmentedControl*)sender{ 
if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {     
    NSLog(@"segment 0");    

}else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex==1){
    NSLog(@"segment 1");

}

}
```

Comment: the selector you provided in viewDidLoad and implemented method are not matching...

Comment: OOps I am sorry .its a typo while writing question.But its same in code.Still it doesnt work.

Comment: First you check whether you initialised 'MyCell' or not ?

Comment: Yes rest of the things in MyCell are working fine except for segmentControl.

Comment: Did you ckeck that maybe it actually does the `selectDeckView:` but it is not going inside any of the `if` statements, so no `NSLog` is execute?

Comment: Yes I have placed a breakpoint over the method.Doesn't reach the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

add the target inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: method instead of `viewDidLoad`

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {


       MyCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
             if (myCell == nil) 
             {

               NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
               myCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

             }

         [myCell.deckSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(selectDeckView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 
         return myCell;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `@selector(selectView:)` and method name should be same.

```
[myCell.deckSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(selectView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];



-(void)selectView:(UISegmentedControl*)sender{ `
`
if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {     
    NSLog(@"segment 0");    

}else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex==1){

NSLog(@"segment 1");

}

}
```

Comment: Yes I know.Its actually same in code.But still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if the selector were wrong ..then there would had been crash ..it seems the Target is getting lost on the cell. Try to add the selector in `ViewDidAppear`. As the view has not appeared, I fear your cell has not been created. Please put a breakpoint in the line

```
[myCell.deckSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(selectDeckView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];  //Also tried UIContolEventTouchUpInside,but doesn't work.
```

and check if the value for `myCell` is `nil` or not ?